# how to burn iso onto dvd?

Tags: drivers, iso, dvd, cd, burning

Unable to burn iso onto dvd, ubuntu startup disk creator doesnt show my dvd drive

**Observation**

1.DVD drive is mounted as read only

2. On windows and ubuntu , when I try to burn iso into disk ,it just ejects the disk after spinning fast .

Comment: I use **`k3b`** to burn isos onto DVD disks. (The Ubuntu Startup Disk Creator is intended for USB boot drives and memory cards).

Comment: Even k3b users have faced this issue, I have already solved my problem

Comment: +1+1; Thanks for making it clear, that also k3b is affected by this issue. I will upvote your question and answer - And again, thanks for sharing your solution :-) By the way, which version of Ubuntu are you running?

Answer (score 1):

Run these commands sequentially in terminal.

1. ```
   sudo apt-get install dvd+rw-tools
   ```
2. ```
   growisofs -Z /dev/sr0=/path/name.iso
   ```
3. If you get input/output error or I/O error example

   ```
   [ PERFORM OPC failed with SK=4h/TRACK FOLLOWING ERROR]: Input/output error
   /dev/sr0: "Current Write Speed" is 8.2x1352KBps.)
   ```

   Use this command

   ```
   growisofs -dvd-compat -speed=2 -Z /dev/sr0=/path/name.iso
   ```

I know speed is quite slow but its quite stable configuration and its most likely to work, but you can experiment with the values

I tried this method on DVD-R x16 dvd on my dvd writer HL-DT-STDVDRAM GT33N, LE01, max UDMA/66

**NOTE:** This method did help many users but in my case ,the image did get burned onto dvd, as i could notice the colour difference, but for some reason the disc still shows as blank, and my bios isn't recognizing that the DVD contains Ubuntu live CD